# UWP DataGridComboBoxColumn converter

Tags: uwp

I'm trying to create a UWP datagrid with dynamically created `DataGridComboBoxColumn` columns that display enum options, but with custom combobox labels. To do this I have:

```
List<EnumDisplay> enums = new List<EnumDisplay>();
EnumConverter converter = new EnumConverter(propertyInfo.PropertyType);
foreach (var kv in converter.Labels)
{
    enums.Add(new EnumDisplay { DisplayName = kv.Key, Value = kv.Value as Enum });
}
Binding binding = new Binding
{
    Path = new PropertyPath(*name of property relevant to this column*),
    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
    Converter = converter
};
DataGridComboBoxColumn col = new DataGridComboBoxColumn()
{                                                 
    ItemsSource = enums
    DisplayMemberPath = nameof(EnumDisplay.DisplayName),
    Binding = binding
};
```

To create the columns, using these classes:

```
internal class EnumDisplay
{
    public Enum Value { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

public class EnumConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> Labels { get; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    internal EnumConverter(Type enumType)
    {
        // Make a dictionary of label names for each value in the enum
        foreach (object value in enumType.GetEnumValues())
        {
            // This static method converts the enum value to the desired string
            string label = Extensions.EnumValueToLabel(enumType, value);
            Labels.Add(label, value);
        }
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        // Lookup the key from the value
        return Labels.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.ToString() == value.ToString()).Key;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        // Lookup the value from the key
        return Labels[value.ToString()];
    }
}
```

However, this produces the error:
*System.ArgumentException: 'The ItemsSource elements do not contain a property [*name of property relevant to this column*]. Ensure that the binding path has been set correctly.'
*

I don't see why the name of the property used by the binding should be applied to the `ItemSource` of the comboboxes. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't but it might help others so I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *System.ArgumentException: 'The ItemsSource elements do not contain a property [name of property relevant to this column]. Ensure that the binding path has been set correctly.' *

I could reproduce your problem, it looks binding context error cause this problem, please feel free report this problem in community tool kit [github](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues). And currently we have a workaround that use string list to replace item list like official [processing](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/4f394ce3e43a77b0f57cd2caf8b32ecc94024cae/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp/Data/DataGridDataSource.cs#L62).  And the other way is set binding `EnumDisplay` property same as DataGrid item one property.

For example, if your `DataGrid` item model contains a property called `Description`, you need set same property name for `EnumDisplay`. It will solve the above exception, but the default DataGridComboBoxColumn cell content will be null.

Comment: Thanks Nico-unfortunately the workarounds don't work in my case (as what they're being bound to is also dynamic) so I'll have to wait for a bug fix.

Comment: Well, if you want to bind a dynamic list, please refer to this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60842557/7254781) update part. that custom  seletct box with DataGridTemplateColumn.  And if above answer or comment is helpful please consider mark it as accept.